# Background image is not displaying at first load

Tags: html, css

for this website : [link](https://www.ctrlz.live/project42/) I need to refresh the page to display the background image. 
I used the same code for this page : [link](https://www.ctrlz.live)  which is working fine. 
The original code come from w3schools and is quiet simple. 
This is the second version of the page and the first was loading with the same problem. 
The image is a .jpeg of 181Ko.

the image class :

```
  <style>
    body, html {height: 100%}
    .bgimg {
      background-image: url('img/42_v8.jpeg');
      min-height: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
```

Which I call in the body

```
<body class="bgimg">
```

How can I improve this ? thx

Comment: No repro here .

Comment: It is working fine for me.

Comment: Could it be on iOS and OS X the problem ?